Key to small for signature creation
I’m trying to sign a PDF document using a third-party API that signs the hash of the PDF. However, when I test the signed PDF with a signature validation tool, I encounter the following error.
The algorithm RSA with key size 256 is too small for signature creation!
Here is a detail error Report created by that tool.
I can also see an undefined error in the signature when opening the PDF in Acrobat reader.
Here’s an outline of my process:

I generate a hash of the PDF document using SHA-256.
I send this hash to the API, which signs it using an RSA private key.
I attach the signature to the PDF and test it with a signature validation tool.
The signature generation works without throwing any errors, but the validation tool flags the above issue.

Here is the code for the contentSigner, which is responsible for signing the content:
 private ContentSigner createContentSigner() {
    return new ContentSigner() {
      // This stream will be filled by the saveIncrementalForExternalSigning method. It holds the bytes of the PDF file.
      private final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      @Override
      public byte[] getSignature() {
        try {
          MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

          // Hash the bytes of the PDF file.
          byte[] hashBytes = digest.digest(stream.toByteArray());
          // The hash is encoded in Base64 as this is the format expected by the server.
          String hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashBytes);

          // Send the hash to the server and retrieve the signed hash.
          // The response is Base64 encoded, so it needs to be decoded for the CMS signature.
          return java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(webAPIService.getSignedHash(hash));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Exception while signing", e);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return stream;
      }

      @Override
      public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier() {
        // The algorithm identifier for SHA-256.
        return new AlgorithmIdentifier(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.1.11"));
      }
    };
  }

Is there a way I can sign that PDF without requesting a bigger keysize from the API-Maintainers?

Please share an example PDF signed by your code for analysis.

That being asked, an RSA key of 256 bits indeed would be far too small to offer any security. But if we were talking about 256 bytes, (2048 bit) the situation would be a bit different, eSig DSS (the validation tool you mentioned) is likely to accept that until 2026. If you need better security and acceptance, switch to at least 3000 bits. But then you should also switch away from RSA-PKCS#1v1_5 and use RSA-PSS (or ECDSA, or a PQC algorithm) instead.

Share the actual literal error messages, including all lines (for example if there is a stack trace). Read [ask].

here is an example PDF which is signed by the code.
I shared the actual literal error message. (The fat text in my post) Sadly, there is no stacktrace since its the conclusion of a validation process in the online tool. But I exported the validation report in an pdf here

Thanks for providing an example PDF. The cause of the issue is that one of your assumptions is wrong:

I send this hash to the API, which signs it using an RSA private key.

No, the API signs it with an ECDSA private key!
Thus, you return the wrong signing algorithm OID in your ContentSigner method getAlgorithmIdentifier, so the signature container you create and embed is inconsistent, an ECDSA signature labeled as RSA signature.
eSig DSS determines that something is wrong and reports that "The signature is not intact!"
The "The algorithm RSA with key size 256 is too small for signature creation!" message is the output of a different check and merely is a red herring in the case at hand.
If you really want RSA signatures, you'll have to talk to your signature provider and ask for a different private key and certificate based on a RSA keypair.
If ECDSA is ok for you, too, you merely need to return the appropriate OID from getAlgorithmIdentifier and continue working from there.

You can verify that the certificate indeed is for an ECDSA key pair, simply inspect it in a certificate viewer (e.g. in Adobe Acrobat):

Alternatively, you can check the eSig DSS diagnostic data for your signature:
        <Certificate Id=...>
            ...
            <PublicKeySize>256</PublicKeySize>
            <PublicKeyEncryptionAlgo>ECDSA</PublicKeyEncryptionAlgo>


As an aside: I just had a look at the structure of the signature container: You have added an unsigned timeStampToken attribute whose value is a GeneralizedTime object. This is completely incorrect and will also result in reports of invalidity in some validators.

Thank you so much for that detailed answer. I switched out the algorithm identifier to ecdsa_with_SHA256 and it passes the validation tool without a problem. I didn't know you can determine the used algorithm based on the public key.
But when I open the pdf with Adobe Acrobat, I can still see issues with the signed pdf. So is there still a problem with Acrobat, is that a false-positive or is it because of the GeneralizedTime object? here is the new signed pdf

"is that a false-positive or is it because of the GeneralizedTime object?" - It's the latter. I just patched the OID of the timestamp attribute to some value without meaning in this context, and now Acrobat is happy with your file.

That sounds positive. So, is there a way to add the unsigned timestamp to the pdf and make Acrobat happy without breaking the validation of the online tool? Here is a gist of my AttributeGenerator

"So, is there a way to add the unsigned timestamp to the pdf and make Acrobat happy without breaking the validation of the online tool?" - Well, you can attach an unsigned timeStampToken attribute, but the value must be an RFC3161 TimeStampToken by a trusted timestamp authority, not a GeneralizedTime object, and that token must timestamp the signature value. Other than that there is no universal, unsigned signing time attribution.

Well thank you very much for that info. This now makes sense. But regarding "I just patched the OID of the timestamp attribute to some value without meaning in this context, and now Acrobat is happy with your file." - couldn't that be done in code and Acrobat is now always happy with my file? Or would that break the online validation on the other hand?

Of course you can continue creating the signature with that invalid attribute and then patch the attribute to something unknown, but why would you want to continue creating that invalid attribute in the first place?

The main reason is, that I want both validation systems to state that the signature is valid. Preferably without external paid TSA.

Which do you mean by "both validation systems"? Do you mean there actually is a validator that requires the signing time as GeneralizedTime in a timeStampToken attribute? Such a validator would require the signature to be invalid in structure, so you should reject the task.

No, sorry. I meant the Acrobat Reader and the Online Validation Tool we have talked about earlier. Regarding those two system, is there a way to sign a pdf without an external paid TSA and that both systems reporting the signature as valid?

Ah ok. Then start by removing that unsigned attribute completely

Oh wow, I didn't knew this was even an option. But now it works.

Where a datetime is needed, depends on the exact profile of signature you want to create. For PAdES BASELINE you need a datetime in the M entry of the signature dictionary as a PDF time object and then optionally (depending on the exact profile) signature timestamps and/or document timestamps. For the old ISO 32000-1 CMS signatures you need a datetime in the M entry or in the signingTime signed attribute, and/or signature timestamps.
